# Get batch input tensor based on batch number

Tags: keras

How can I access the input data for a given batch in a callback that is triggered at batch end? I can find out the batch number but that's just an integer. I would like to access the input tensor that is fed to the input layer, in other words the training data of the batch. This is dependent on the given epoch since the data is shuffled with each new epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [training loop](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/bf1378f39d02b7d0b53ece5458f9275ac8208046/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L205) doesn't pass the input so you can't from the arguments. One option would be to have access to the data and compute data points yourself based on the `batch_index` provided:

```
def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
  dpoints = data[batch * batch_size:(batch + 1) * batch_size]
```

You can set it as class fields when creating the callback as well if your data is not global.

Comment: That's exactly my question. How can I access the shuffled data for the epoch?

Comment: You can't if you are using `model.fit` the shuffled indices are encapsulated. So you need to implement your own data `Sequence` [doc](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) which you can use to get batches.